# Ubuntu 16.04 boots without console access or options

Tags: boot, command-line, 16.04, ssh, uefi

**Machine**:

An older dell optiplex. It has ubuntu 16.04 as the only OS installed on it. The machine uses UEFI.

**Problem**:

I upgraded packages via apt to get the latest version of a system library needed on a recently upgraded service. All was successful, all services worked. After about 24 hours, I attempted to ssh back into the machine and noticed that ssh was not running. Going direct to the machine, I attached a monitor and keyboard where I saw errors.

```
*ERROR* uncleared pch fifo underrun on pch transcoder A

*ERROR* PCH transcoder A FIFO underrun
```

No console was available so I rebooted it. The same errors are shown and a console is never available even after waiting hours. However, I know the system boots because other services are started just fine but ssh.

Running an nmap against the machine shows me this

```
PORT     STATE SERVICE
21/tcp   open  ftp
25/tcp   open  smtp
53/tcp   open  domain
80/tcp   open  http
111/tcp  open  rpcbind
389/tcp  open  ldap
443/tcp  open  https
5666/tcp open  nrpe
```

**Toubleshooting done**:

I have seen other threads with the same error, but all of those require accessing either a command line or grub. Booting does not give me access to a command line, and I have attempted multiple times with different keys (both shift keys, esc, etc) when booting to get into grub.

Comment: Try disrupting the boot to see if it thinks the last boot failed so it will bring up the GRUB.  As soon as it starts to boot to the OS, kill the power to the host.  Then try to boot it again.  Other than that, you could always try booting to a Live USB/DVD to access it that way.

Comment: @Terrance And by disrupting boot you mean? I have tried holding down shift, tapping shift, holding down esc, tapping esc, etc.

Comment: I mean by killing the power.

Comment: @Terrance that did it! Thanks

Comment: No problem!  Just a little trick we learned at my job for when we needed to get Ubuntu hosts into single user mode and we couldn't access grub.  What we figure is that after a certain point in the boot it will flag the bootloader as successful, so if we killed the power shortly after it started loading it would bring up the grub on the next reboot.  Very helpful for us as well!  =)